# Spring Rest Respository : is it safe?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data

With spring-data a `@RepositoryRestResource` allow me to perform CRUD operations for a given `@Entity` class. All is impressively magical but how can I add a security layer to prevent anybody to call a million times the insertion URL?

Comment: Did you mean "prevent" instead of "provide"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems, this problem is not specific to Spring Data REST. If you have any public interface that allows to add data to your database, you have the same problem.

However, regarding Spring Data REST, there are (at least) two possibilities:

### Don't export the `save(T)` method

Use `@RestResource(exported = false)` to prevent Spring Data REST to export certain methods at all:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(path = "people", rel = "people")
interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Long> {

  @Override
  @RestResource(exported = false)
  void save(Person person);

}
```

You can still use the `save(T)` method in your code, but it won't be available via REST. See [the reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#customizing-sdr.hiding-repository-crud-methods) for more details.

### Secure your application with Spring Security

Require users to log in before they are allowed to save data. Spring Data REST provides an example that shows how to secure a Spring Data REST application in multiple ways with Spring Security: [Spring Data REST + Spring Security](http://secure%20a%20Spring%20Data%20REST%20application%20in%20multiple%20ways%20with%20Spring%20Security)

Comment: Great! Thank you for your answer :)!